# What is a word called that consists of a repetition of one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, repetition

What is a word called that consists of a repetition of one word?

I came across the word *polypoly* in one of the other question asked on the site, and it got me thinking whether there are other English words that are made up of a word or part of a word repeated in the same way that *polypoly* is made up of *poly + poly*. Can you please provide examples also?

Comment: The word was actually _polyopoly_, if I remember correctly, not polypoly.

Comment: I think both are acceptable spellings, according to the post anyway: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171868/what-is-the-opposite-of-a-monopoly/171961#171961

Comment: This question is not too broad. He said "some" examples, we cannot list all of them obviously. Also, we know what it is called now so more examples can be searched. There are similar list-request questions in the past that is open also.

Comment: @Michael Lai: You may modify the question title and body to ask what this formation is called instead of asking for examples only. And you can ask for some examples in the question body.

Comment: They'll be matched by the regexp `^(.*)-?\1$`

Answer (score 11):

This is called *reduplication*. If you repeat the whole word (or lexeme), it is called *full reduplication*. There is usually a hyphen in between. (For example: go-go)

There is a list of English reduplications here: 
[http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_reduplications](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_reduplications)

Full reduplication examples:

- boo-boo
- bye-bye
- cancan
- chop-chop
- gee-gee
- jaw-jaw
- licky-licky
- moo-moo
- murmur
- nulla-nulla
- pee-pee
- pompom
- poo-poo
- pooh-pooh
- rah-rah
- tartar
- dodo
- lulu
- tutu
- juju
- papa
- couscous
- tete
- coco
- dik-dik
- beriberi

Comment: ... and a look-alike: _hotshots_

Comment: @Edwin: Great example! Maybe we can call it pseudo-reduplication :)

Comment: *Tartar* is another example of a word that looks superficially like reduplication (*tar + tar*).

Comment: @snailboat It might very well be in French (define: tartare), but in English the word has become tartare

Comment: @MichaelLai *Tartare* is [chopped up meat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steak_tartare), but *tartar* is like [tartar sauce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartar_sauce).

Comment: Many of these are not English at all, but loan words from other languages. `cancan` and `tutu` are French. Many others are from Pacific languages where reduplication is very common.

Comment: @teylyn: Loan words are _English_ also.

Comment: Rhetorical question: why is it *re* duplication? Repeating or duplication, I understand. But reduplication is using too many superfluous unnecessary redundant syllables. Unless the word has *four* occurrences of the same component word. Illogical ... natural language ... sigh ... mutter ... (wanders off).

Comment: It may be worth noting that *testes* is not reduplicated, but rather the plural form of *testis.*

Comment: @Anonym: I thought it would count. I will delete then to eliminate confusion.

Comment: @Anonym: Also you gave me food for thought. Are you sure we cannot call testes reduplication? Because think this way, when you change the word from singular to plural you are reduplicating it. Though I might ask this as a question also.

Comment: @ermanen Note that *testis, testes* follows a specific Latin declension in which singular *-is* is replaced with plural *-es.*  Some other nouns belonging to the same declension: *axis, axes; thesis, theses; oasis, oases.*  So *testes* does *appear* to have been reduplicated, but the process by which it has been created is not reduplication.

Comment: @Anonym: You are right. But I still feel like we can call it both  a plural and a reduplication :) Do you think this is worth to ask as a question?  (with some additional details of course)

Comment: @ermanen  Perhaps.  If it were asked as a broader question about what exactly constitutes reduplication, then I think that it might be interesting.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement ermanen's list, I note these from *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> *ack-ack* (n.)
>
> *agar-agar* (n.)
>
> *atlatl* (n.)
>
> *aye-aye* (n.)
>
> *Berber* (n.)
>
> *bonbon* (n.)
>
> *buddy-buddy* (adj.)
>
> *bulbul* (n.)
>
> *caracara* (n.)
>
> *cha-cha* (n.)
>
> *chowchow* (n.—the relish not the dog, which is spelled *chow chow*)
>
> *dumdum* (n.—the bullet)
>
> *dum-dum* (n.—the nitwit)
>
> *gaga* (adj.)
>
> *go-go* (adj.)
>
> *goody-goody* (adj.)
>
> *goo-goo* (adj. & n.)
>
> *gris-gris* (n.)
>
> *ha-ha* (interj.)
>
> *ha-ha* (n.—a sunk fence)
>
> *lavalava* (n.—has nothing to do with volcanic lava)
>
> *mau-mau* (v.)
>
> *meme* (n.)
>
> *motmot* (n.)
>
> *mumu* (n., from MW's Unabridged dictionary)
>
> *no-no* (n.)
>
> *pawpaw* (n.)
>
> *so-so* (adj. & adv.)
>
> *tsetse* (n.)
>
> *tut-tut* (interj. & v.)

For some reason, Merriam-Webster's doesn't acknowledge the reality of *hubba-hubba*. But I'm sure that there are others in the dictionary that I've missed...

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help :) I learned some new words also!

Comment: Out of context and just scrolling, these answers are absolutely hilarious.

Answer (score 2):

Such a word is a *tautonym*. See sense 2 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tautonym#Noun): "(linguistics) A word or term made from two identical parts or syllables, such as bonbon or dada."