# Is "testes" an inflectional reduplication?

Tags: morphology, word-formation, reduplication

I was supposed to ask this question 1 year ago and it is based on a discussion in this question that I answered:
[What is a word called that consists of a repetition of one word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172083/what-is-a-word-called-that-consists-of-a-repetition-of-one-word)

I gave *testes* as an example of a full reduplication and a commentator told me that "*testes* is not reduplicated, but rather the plural form of *testis*".

I know that it is a plural form and it is chiefly in plural form but I thought we can consider *testes* both a plural form and a reduplication. It is not created by reduplication process but a pattern is reduplicated when you use the plural form. He also noted that *testis, testes* follows a specific Latin declension in which singular *-is* is replaced with plural *-es*. Some other nouns belonging to the same declension: *axis, axes; thesis, theses; oasis, oases.*

[Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) of *reduplication*:

> Reduplication in linguistics is a morphological process in which **the root or stem of a word (or part of it)** or even the whole word is repeated exactly or with a slight change.

The definition says that the repeated part can even be part of the root or stem of a word. I know that the word *testes* is not created with the usual reduplication process but there is also a form called *inflectional reduplication*:

> A still stricter definition of reduplication would only include inflectional reduplication, i.e., only a
>   reduplication which serves a clear-cut grammatical function, is to be considered an 'actual' form
>   of reduplication, thereby excluding lexical reduplicate forms. Inflectional reduplication, is
>   however probably the most uncommon of all forms of reduplication. Inflectional reduplication is
>   manifested either as a full reduplication or as a partial reduplication, i.e., the copying of only a
>   part of the base.
>
> <sub>Source: http://reduplication.uni-graz.at/texte/Other_Red_Phen.pdf</sub>

Can someone please shed light on this?

<sub>Note: *Testes* is also one of the plural forms of *test* meaning "The cupel used in treating gold or silver alloys or ore; now esp. the cupel, with the iron frame or basket which contains it, forming the movable hearth of a reverberatory furnace" *[OED]*</sub>

---

Another controversial word is *tartar*.

For the proper noun *Tartar* (meaning "a native inhabitant of the region of central Asia extending eastward from the Caspian Sea, and formerly known as Independent and Chinese Tartary." *OED*), the book "Journal of the Royal Asiatic Society of Great Britain and Ireland" has the following:

[image]

Comment: The text in the png image is not applying the term *reduplication* to the term *Tartar* itself but rather addressing the use of reduplication in Tartar languages.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Thanks for the clarification. I couldn't be sure when I found it and I couldn't find further information in the book.  "Tartar" is a language also (which is called "Tatar" also) and the origin of the word is 'tatar" as well which is a word in that language and can be considered a reduplication.

Comment: Have you considered asking this question on Linguistics SE? I think it's very relevant, since "reduplication" is linguistic terminology.

Comment: @sumelic: I can consider if I don't get an answer on here. It is on-topic on here too.

Comment: There is a great difference between reduplication (night-night; razzle-dazzle) and the accidental  phenomenon of repeated letters (hotshots).

Comment: @Edwin: Reduplication is not only word repetition. Hotshots is a different case (lexeme is not repeated) and you mentioned it 1 year ago also in the question I linked to. I said we might call it pseudo-reduplication.

Comment: _Testes_ is the plural nominative form of _testis_ (which is the singular nominative form). It is not reduplication. If you want reduplication, look at Latin perfect verb stems, not noun inflections. English doesn't really have any inflectional reduplication, but we have any number of reduplicated idioms, and some productive reduplicated syntactic constructions.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Thanks. That clearly answers my question. I am aware that it is a plural form and I mentioned how it is formed but I wondered if "testes" can be considered both a plural form and a reduplication. For example, can "tes" be considered part of the lexeme? The right term would be inflectional reduplication as you said but it seems like English doesn't have. I wonder if other languages have that. It would be nice if you post your comment as an answer with some details.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't split up like that. _Testis_ originally meant 'witness', and etymologically the _te_- part comes from an older _tri_-, a combining form of the word for 'three', and -_stis_ is derived from the Indo-European root **stā*- meaning 'stand.'  (I have no idea how "three" got involved here, btw)

Comment: @JohnLawler A witness is a third-party observer.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Prof. Lawler, I found [this source](http://reduplication.uni-graz.at/texte/Other_Red_Phen.pdf) and other sources that mentions "inflectional reduplication" as a type of reduplication. It says it is probably the most uncommon one. I couldn't find a source that English has inflectional reduplications. I'm not sure if all sources mention this term for other languages. One source was talking about inflectional reduplications in Tagalog.

Comment: English hardly has inflections, let alone inflectional reduplications. We have freezes like _wishy-washy_ and _helter-skelter_, and productive lexical reduplicative constructions like "Blizzard, Shmizzard". [Lushootseed](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed.html) has inflectional reduplications; #6 in the link has examples of three different varieties of root reduplication.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key point is that Wikipedia refers to reduplication as a *process*, not a relationship. That *testes* starts and ends with the same three letters is a fact. But historically, this fact does not derive from any kind of process of repetition. Otherwise, we'd get *thesis, thethe* and so on.

You seem to already realize that "tes" is not the actual stem of the word, but you try to get around this by appealing to the idea of partial reduplication. By this logic, you would have to include even more ridiculous examples: any suffixed word that happens to include the sounds of the suffix in the stem. For example: *singing, prizes, flitted.*

(And lastly, the repetition here merely applies to the spelling, as Edwin Ashworth notes.)

Answer (score 1):

The Italian Wikipedia article has some more examples on reduplication in Latin and they are not quite similar to what happens in *testes*: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplicazione#Lingue_con_reduplicazione

The key, in my opinion, is that the speaker doesn't perceive a repetition at all in *testes*. We should check further sources, but as an Italian speaker I pronounce the first *e* more open than the second: /'tɛstes/ (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_italiana#Vocali) which in Latin might have been /'testeːs/ (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_latina#Vocali).

Of course there are differing opinions on how Latin was pronounced, but here we really have no element at all to support the idea of a reduplication.

Comment: Yes, I understand this and added relevant details but there is some evidence to support inflectional reduplication.