# Words like "no-no" and "boo-boo"

Tags: linguistics

I was just thinking about these words and was curious what they might be called. After a little scrounging around on Google, the best answer I could come up with was "reduplication." This doesn't seem to be the best fit though, as it focuses on meaning through the duplication, and not the duplication itself.

I was wondering, though these terms are generally used in endearing relationships such as with children or significant others, does anyone know if words like these follow a linguistic tendency/rule/etc., and does it have a better name?

Comment: "reduplication" seems redundant.

Comment: relevant (and possible dupe): [What is a word called that consists of a repetition of one word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172083/what-is-a-word-called-that-consists-of-a-repetition-of-one-word)

Comment: @Cascabel Not sure how I missed this post! It seems to be a duplicate to what I'm asking. I'm still not totally satisfied with reduplication being the resulting answer, but thanks for finding it for me!

Comment: I suspect those particular examples would also be considered *baby-talk* by most folks. The Wikipedia article on reduplication even calls [English examples of exact reduplication "(baby-talk-like)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication#Examples).

Comment: Reduplication is not common in English. That's just English, though. It's quite common in many other languages. [The Lushootseed language](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed.html), for instance, has about a dozen varieties of reduplication, partial and full, prefixal and suffixal, general (noun plural and diminutive) and specialized (counting money, naming languages, etc). [There are four types in this data puzzle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed-6.pdf).

Comment: There are several types of reduplication in English (edit), including "schm", ablaut, rhyming etc. Only "schm" is productive in speech, meaning new language can be formed from them (AFAIK). If you are looking for an answer about the exact reduplication and linguistic tendencies, you might want to take it up at Linguistics.SE, but I am pretty sure this topic has been done to death.